# If $|G|=2p$ then $G$ is cyclic or dihedral

Tags: group-theory

I have found the following proof for this
https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/groups-of-order-2p/

it says that when $p=2$ it is trivial, why is it?

Comment: If you feel uncomfortable with this, you can do the case $p=2$ by yourself. One does it in a similar fashion. Choose $a\in G\setminus \{ e\}$, either $G$ is cyclic or there exists $b\in G \setminus \langle a \rangle$. Now you can go through the rest of the proof and make minor changes to get the "trivial" case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trivial for $p=2$ because the only groups of order $4$ up to isomorphism are  $C_4$ and $D_4$.

By $D_4$, I mean the dihedral group of order $4$ (sometimes written $D_2$). This is isomorphic to the Klein four group, $C_2\times C_2$.